# How do I store a script in a Variable?

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm trying to make a function to convert powershell scripts to Base64

As dumb as this sounds I am stuck just trying to store a small script in a variable.

Im trying to write ONE function that can encode and decode either a string or a file into Base64.
Everything works fine except encoding a string.
Passing a simple string as a variable works fine

ex: "this string will work no problem"

it is when i try to pass a literal string where the issues come in.

"$p = "notepad";start $p"

cannot be passed through the parameter without errors

keep in mind I am making this function for other people too so i cannot control what they pass through the variable.

```
function B64 {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="encFile")]
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encFile")]
    [string]
    $encFile,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="encString")]
    [string]
    $encString,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decFile")]
    [string]
    $decFile,

    [Parameter(Position=0, ParameterSetName="decString")]
    [string]
    $decString

)

if ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encFile") {
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $encFile -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        return $encoded
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "encString") {
        $File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
        Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $File -Value $encString    
        $encoded = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes((Get-Content -Path $File -Raw -Encoding UTF8)))
        Remove-Item $File
        return  $encoded
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decFile") {
        $data = Get-Content $decFile
        $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
        return $decoded     
        }

elseif ($psCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq "decString") {
        $File = "$env:TEMP\foob64.txt"
        Set-Content -NoNewline -Path $File -Value $decString
        $data = Get-Content $File       
        $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($data))
        Remove-Item $File
        return $decoded
        }
}
```

Comment: `$String = "$p = 'notepad';start $p"` does work, `$p` is never defined.

Comment: yes yes indeed that is the issue, now I need a solution. The contents of $String are being passed in from a parameter, so how do i properly store it?

Comment: To answer the question in your title, you store it like this `$String = { $p = "notepad";start $p }` and execute it like this `& $String`

Comment: problem is I am not trying to execute it. 
I am trying to take that script in as a parameter in a function 
and then convert it to base64 and store it in the $encoded variable

Comment: in that case, you need to use single-quotes, so the variables don't expand and remain literal strings: `$String = '$p = ''notepad'';start $p'`

Comment: that can't be the only solution. this function is not just for me. I do not have control of what others pass through that variable

Comment: You can use a single-quote here-string.

Comment: What function? Why don’t you update your post with what you’re *actually* trying to do. It sounds like to me you need to simply type your parameter as a string in your function and then whatever is passed in will be a string.

Comment: updating right now

Comment: If the string you're passing contains double-quotes or variables you'll want to surround your string with single quotes. `B64 -encString '$p = "notepad";start $p' ` works just fine and the result decodes properly back to the original string

Comment: yea that does work, I just put a huge warning in the readme file that the encString input needs to be in single quotes

Comment: The caller has the responsibility to ensure what they pass into the function. If they are passing variables then they need to ensure the variables don’t expand prematurely if that is their intention.